# Unknown column '2' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

its a simple code but I'm just learning it so...  I can't seem to find what my error is exactly:

```
"UPDATE `".$table_name_4_updating."`
            SET id_capuchon = `".$id_selector_4_updating."`,
                referencia_capuchon= `".$referencia_4_updating."`,
                medida_capuchon= `".$medida_4_updating."`,
                material_capuchon= `".$material_4_updating."`,
                calibre_capuchon= `".$calibre_4_updating."`,
                impresion_capuchon= `".$impresion_4_updating."`,
                presentacion_capuchon= `".$presentacion_4_updating."`
             WHERE id_capuchon=`".$id_selector_4_updating."`";
```

I tried changing the the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE id_capuchon= '.$id_selector_4_updating.'`
and other different ways but all it does is changes from `unknown column foobar in field list`

Comment: You have the wrong quotes. Change backticks to single-quotes (`'`).

Comment: In other words, you've got ``where foo=`2` ``.

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages; you just happen to use the former to generate code for the latter. When you have a SQL error you need to inspect the actual SQL code and possibly test it in your favourite MySQL client.

Comment: yes and I've changed it from (`)  to (')  and  changed from in 'where clause' to  'field list '

Comment: Remove backticks in `".$id_selector_4_updating."` and add single quotes `'".$id_selector_4_updating."'` and do the same for the rest. Then `WHERE id_capuchon='$id_selector_4_updating'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `backticks` around the value in the WHERE clause (and in every assignment too, actually).
This type of quotes is used in SQL to **refer to a field name**. So here, MySQL is looking for the field named "2" (the value of your variable `$id_selector_4_updating`) but this field doesn't exist, hence the error.
You should remove them:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE $table_name_4_updating SET
             id_capuchon = '$id_selector_4_updating',
             referencia_capuchon = '$referencia_4_updating',
             medida_capuchon = '$medida_4_updating',
             material_capuchon = '$material_4_updating',
             calibre_capuchon = '$calibre_4_updating',
             impresion_capuchon = '$impresion_4_updating',
             presentacion_capuchon = '$presentacion_4_updating'
         WHERE id_capuchon ='$id_selector_4_updating'";
```

Comment: when i remove the backticks the error is now : `Unknown column '2' in 'field list'`

Comment: so why is it that in this case it does work ? `  $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `".$company_table_name."`(`id_capuchon`, `referencia_capuchon`, `medida_capuchon`, `material_capuchon`, `calibre_capuchon`, `impresion_capuchon`, `presentacion_capuchon`) 
VALUES('', '$referencia_cap', '$medida_cap', '$material_cap', '$calibre_cap', '$impresion_cap', '$presentacion_cap')"; `

Comment: <the backticks were removed but each element highlighted has them>

Answer (score 3):

You should change the backtick (`` ` ``) characters to single quotes (`'`).

**Example:**

```
UPDATE
    $table_name_4_updating
    SET
        id_capuchon = '$id_selector_4_updating',
        referencia_capuchon = '$referencia_4_updating',
        medida_capuchon = '$medida_4_updating',
        material_capuchon = '$material_4_updating',
        calibre_capuchon = '$calibre_4_updating',
        impresion_capuchon = '$impresion_4_updating',
        presentacion_capuchon = '$presentacion_4_updating'
    WHERE id_capuchon = '$id_selector_4_updating'
```

Comment: also tried that it didn't  work ... changed from  in 'where clause' to  field list

Comment: +1 since you were the first to answer. OP chose the other answer instead.